# session get attribute of a boolean value

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

In my servlet, JSP application, I've used a session variable to store log in status whether the user is logged into the system OR not.The value is a Boolean.

```
session.setAttribute("sess_login",true);
```

Now when i check this value in login page after log out, i get a NullPointer Exception on the below line.

```
boolean login=((Boolean) session.getAttribute("sess_login")).booleanValue();
```

But this works fine if i store a string value in session variable.

Can anyone explain me the reason behind it?

Comment: The relevant part of the code here is how exactly you clear this attribute on logout. Please show it.

Comment: "But this works fine if i store a string value in session variable." can you post your code in case of String in session variable??

Answer (score 7):

I tested your code and it worked correctly. I think you are doing some mistake in your testing.

In your code if `sess_login` attribute doesn't exist in session object, a `NullPointerException` will throw(I think this is your problem).

To prevent throwing exception that is better to use following code:

```
if(session().getAttribute("status") != null){
    boolean value = (Boolean) req.getSession().getAttribute("status");
}
```

Comment: How about `boolean value = req.getSession().getAttribute("status") == Boolean.TRUE`?